# Kexec does'n work

Tags: kernel, reboot

I've got some problem with `kexec -e` command:

I use `kexec -l` to load a kernel, or `pxe-kexec`.

Then I type `kexec -e`and the result is a complete freeze of the system (no keyword works but ctrl+alt+canc that do a hardware reboot)

If I do `kexec -e` out of the GUI (`sudo service lightdm stop`) the last thing that i can see is:

```
[ 000.000000] Starting new kernel
_
```

then it freeze.

Is there someone that could help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how it worked for me (following [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=785347)):

## With X display manager:

Sometimes the display manager may get in the way, so I suggest to stop it. The command to stop its something like (depending in the display manager you are using):

```
service lightdm stop
```

After stopping it, you may need to move to another console (Ctrl+Alt+F#).

## Loading the kernel:

Execute as root:

```
KERNEL_TO_LOAD=$(uname -r)
kexec -l --append="`cat /proc/cmdline`" --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-${KERNEL_TO_LOAD} /boot/vmlinuz-${KERNEL_TO_LOAD}
sync
umount -a
kexec -e
```

The above code will restart the current kernel (provided by `uname -r`). To load the last installed kernel (e.g. restart after update), change the first line to:

```
KERNEL_TO_LOAD=$(ls /lib/modules | sort -Vr | head -n 1)
```

This answer is mainly for testing purposes, so I would suggest to follow [fman23 recommendations](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=975968) to change the reboot script if you want to use it regularly (like in a server).